# libgdx: Request GPS geolocation?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, gps, libgdx

Is there a way to get the users geolocation using libgdx? Or do I have to implement it for Android and iOS independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the LibGDX framework does not have an implementation for GPS. You will have to write platform specific code. The Gdx.input class gives you access to the accelerometer, compass, etc.

Here is a link to a post about [features](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1832) for LibGDX.

Edit:

I did a quick search just to double check, someone did write an implementation for android [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3354). You might be able to use this.